# php throws fatal error but application continues

Tags: php, zend-framework2, fatal-error

I am working on a ZF2 project and I found this really strange behaviour.

The code, at the beginning of a view, is this:

```
<?php 
    $sl = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator();
    $routeMatch = $sl->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
    var_dump(is_object($routeMatch));
    var_dump(method_exists($routeMatch, 'getMatchedRouteName'));
    $route = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
    var_dump($route);die;
?>
```

The first two `var_dump` print `true` and the last `var_dump` prints a string, so the application clearly reaches that point.

Anyhow, every time the application runs, I find in the Apache error log the following fatal error:

> PHP Fatal Error: Call to a member function getMatchedRouteName() 
>       on a non-object

Why does this happen? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Well someone ain't telling the truth:)  You 100% certain the error logged corresponds to where you are testing?  No forwarding/re-routing of request?

Comment: It's likely you're getting this on 404 pages, i.e. where there was no matched route. Is this view used on such pages?

Comment: @ficuscr that is the only place where such function is called, and the file name and line number in the error log correspond, so I am pretty sure

Comment: @TimFountain actually I put that piece of code in the view of the homepage of the project, so there is no 404 involved

Comment: In the view...?  I assumed controller.  Makes me kinda wonder... could see `is_callable` returning true... the `method_exists` though and what you describe is confusing me.

Comment: @TimFountain eventually I found the reason for my problem. You can see my answer below. You were right! A 404 was the reason for my problem. Sorry if initially I dismissed your useful comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was probable, everybody was telling the truth!

I can see the code working because it is working for that particular HTTP request.

Anyway, loading the webpage there are some other HTTP requests for other contents (css, images, ...).

One of those files is missing.

Apache is configured that if the request asks for a file and the file does not exist, then the request is forwarded to index.php, i.e. in to my zf2 application. Since no route is matching the request then the application shows a 404 message.

Zf2 is preconfigured in a way that the layout.phtml (where my code is) is showed also in the 404 page. And it is there that the error happened.

My excuses to @TimFountain, since his suggestion is correction and I initially dismissed it.